# Are persistent sockets persistent across routers and other in between machines?

Tags: flash, sockets, network-programming

How do persistent sockets work across routers on the web.I am planning to open a persistent Flash socket between a machine and a remote machine. There may be several machines in between those. Do each of these maintain a persistent socket continuously?
How would such a scenario scale up to the millions of users on the web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two types of socket connections, stream based (like TCP) and datagram based (like UDP).

Even an open TCP connection is merely just a entry in the routing table of each machine on the path from source to target. An open connection does not consume CPU power by itself, only the packets sent do.

So to answer your question: Yes, every machine in between maintains this socket connection but it is perfectly fine and scales very well.

Answer (score 1):

Routers on the internet usually are not keeping track of connections at the TCP level. Typically they just have routing rules to know how to forward IP traffic to the next hop on the Internet for the destination address in an IP packet.

Now your router/NAT that your ISP gives you for your home does some connection tracking logic to map your public IP to the connections associated with your PCs behind the NAT.  But that's the exception, not the rule.

"sockets" and "connections" are concepts and state maintained by the two endpoints of a TCP/IP session. Everything in between is (in theory, but not necessary in practice) stateless.